# Induction Proof: $(1+x)^n = 1+x^n$ for even $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, induction

I'm trying to work on a proof by induction. The statement is:

Let n be even. Then, $(x+1)^n = x^n + 1$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup{0}$ and $(x^n+1) \in  \mathbb{F}_2[x]$

Base case: $n=0$ and $n=2$ both satisfy the condition, fairly trivially. I include the $n=2$ case specifically to draw upon later.

We suppose true for $n=2k$ (as we require n even), so that we assume:

$(x+1)^{2k} = x^{2k} + 1$

Then, if $n=2k+2$:

$(x+1)^{2k+2} = (x+1)^{2k} (x+1)^2$

$\Rightarrow (x+1)^{2k+2} = (x^{2k}+1)(x^2+1)$, where the first RHS bracket follows from the inductive assumption, and the second bracket was shown to hold earlier.

Then, expanding RHS gives:

$(x+1)^{2k+2} = x^{2k+2} + 1 + x^2 + x^{2k}$

This is where I come unstuck. I'm hoping to show that $(x+1)^{2k+2} = x^{2k+2} + 1$ , but I can't see a way to get rid of the extra terms on the RHS to complete my proof.

For what it's worth, the actual question I'm working on simply concerns the case $n=6$, and while I could do this by showing that (x+1) is a factor, then divide it out, and then show that (x+1) is still a factor, and repeat 6 times, that feels like an unusually ugly approach. I can't see any other obvious way to handle the problem, so hints appreciated.

Comment: Note that $(x+1)^n$ and $x^n + 1$ do not define the same polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ (as carmichael561 has shown). However, their values coincide for all $x \in \mathbb{F}_2$ as is easily seen by plugging the 2 different possible values into the equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1+x)^6=1+6x+15x^2+20x^3+15x^4+6x^5+x^6$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, hence
$$ (1+x)^6=1+x^2+x^4+x^6 $$
in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$. So the claim isn't true. It is however the case that $(1+x)^n=1+x^n$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ if $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Right. I checked for n = 0, 2 and 4 and it seemed to work out. If only I'd gone one step further. Thanks for the fast help.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to prove isn't true: $(1 + x)^n = 1 + x^n$ in $\Bbb{F_2}[x]$ iff $n$ is a power of two (check the case $n=6$ if you don't believe me). [Sierpiniski's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) gives a nice visualisation of how the binomial coefficients work modulo $2$.